# casperJS How select element(s) by specific starting text with querySelector or querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs, selectors-api

I have to use casperJS to upload one file to a customer server, now before uploading I need to emulate a click on two specific links, these links (simple HTML anchors) don't have a name/id/class... (really ugly HTML code) so I have the only option to select it by it's text content.

How can I find it using the `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` methods?

So far, I could come up with the following (unsuccessful attempts) :(

```
querySelector("a[text()='texttofind']");
querySelector("a[text='texttofind']");
querySelector("a[text=texttofind]");
```

**EDIT AFTER ALL SUGGESTION**

**TITLE UPDATED**
to be more specific about my problem that seem related only to casperjs

**PLATFORM**
- Windows 7
- CasperJS version 1.1.0-beta3
- phantomjs version 1.9.7
- Python 2.7

so, probably i'm too dumb :( now i post a complete example that sadly don't work for me :(

**HTML main index**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST Main Page</title>
</head>
<frameset cols="100,100" >
    <frame name="menu_a" src="menu_1.html">
    <frame name="menu_b" src="menu_2.html">
</frameset>
</html>
```

**HTML menu_1.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST Menu 1</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:red;">
<h3>Menu 1</h3>
<select onchange="javscript:alert('test')" id="test" size="1" name="systemID">
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">TestMenu1            </option>
    <option value="17">TestMenu2                               </option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML menu_2.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST Menu 1</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:orange;">
<h3>Menu 2</h3>
 <a href="javascript:alert('test')"><b>clickhere   </b></a>
 <a href="javascript:alert('noclickhere')"><b>NoClickHere   </b></a>
</body>
</html>
```

**CasperJS script**

start equal for all tests:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start(serverName, function(){});
```

**first test - clicklabel as suggested by @Ka0s**

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.withFrame('menu_b', function(){
        this.clickLabel('clickhere', 'a');
    });
});
```

result:

```
CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: xpath selector: //a[text()="test"]
  /bin/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1355 in mouseEvent
  /bin/casperjs/modules/casper.js:462 in click
  /bin/casperjs/modules/casper.js:487 in clickLabel
  /test.js:90
  /bin/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1553 in runStep
  /bin/casperjs/modules/casper.js:399 in checkStep
```

this not work even if i cleanup the string removing blank spaces at the end of the clickhere string on my test code.

**second test - xPath as sugggested by @ArtjomB**

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.withFrame('menu_b', function(){
    this.evaluate(function(){
     var element = __utils__.getElementByXPath("//a[starts-with(text(),'clickhere')]");
     console.log(element);
    });
 });
});
```

result:

```
remote message caught: undefined
```

so i suppose that the xPath fail finding the element.

**Third test - querySelectorAll with for loop as suggested by @Brunis**

This is a strange beaviour, casperJS return the content of href instead the object
this not seem an error on below code but a problem on my implementation or something else.

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.withFrame('menu_b', function(){
        this.evaluate(function(){
        var as = document.querySelectorAll("a");
        var match = "clickhere";
        var elems = [];     
        for (var i=0; i<as.length; i++){
            if (as[i].textContent === match) {
                elems.push(as[i]);
            }
        }
        console.log(elems[0]);
    });
 });
});
```

Result:
 remote message caught: javascript:alert('test')

i obtain the href code not the  object! if i try this example in a fiddle, i receive the object and i can call onclick() on it.

Comment: Text content is not an attribute of its parent node; it's a node type in and of itself. You are not going to be able to do this using `querySelector`. You'll have to use JS to inspect the text content of each `a` element and then operate on it once you find a match.

Comment: Palpatim is correct, find all the a elements first, then filter out the ones you don't want in a simple for loop.

Comment: Why don't you use XPath instead?

Comment: Thank you all! @BoltClock how can i use xPath in casperJS evaluation? i'm not be able to use it.. i try with this:                       var xPath = require('casper').selectXPath; this.evaluate(function(){element = xPath('//a[[text()="SampleText"]'); }); but seem not work :( i get xPath as null reference

Comment: The error you get from "my code" is not my code, it's your onchange event that fires the alert.

Comment: sorry @Brunis I not mean that is an error in your code! i mean that casperJS act in a strange way and return the content of href instead the object! probably is my error but i can't understand where this error is :(

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple loop that matches the text of the link you want and adds them to an array:

the html:

```
<div>
    <a name="test">not this one</a>
    <a name="test">not this one</a>
    <a name="test">not this one</a>
    <a name="test">not this one</a>
    <a name="test">this one</a>
</div>
```

and the script:

```
var as = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var match = "this one";
var elems = [];

for (var i=0; i<as.length; i++){
    if (as[i].textContent === match) {
        elems.push(as[i]);
    }
}
```

now you have the matched elements in the elems array.

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/0pLd8s9r/

Comment: thank you, this seem work  on browser but casperJs have a strange behavior on your code. If i do console.log(elems[0]) on browser (firefox) it return [a] object so i can do elems[0].onclick() to fire click event. but if i do the same on casperJs i receive the content on the href  not the object!!

Comment: Remove the onchange="javascript:alert('test')" from your select in html

Answer (score 3):

If you anyway know the text within the anchor, try clickLabel. This is what I use

```
this.clickLabel('Anchor_Text','a')
```

Where Anchor_Text is the complete text in the anchor

Found [here](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#clicklabel)

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector(All)` will not let you specify the content of the element you're looking for. You would have to look into each anchor individually.

You could try something like this:

```
var hrefs = document.getElementById('all_anchors').querySelectorAll('a');
for (var x=0;x<hrefs.length;x++) {
    if (hrefs[x].innerHTML==text) {
        alert(hrefs[x].href);   
    }
}
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kavcqtx/))

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused with page context. Everything that is executed inside an `evaluate` callback is sandboxed. It will cannot see variables on the outside or the outside cannot see variables on the inside. They have to be specifically passed and can only be composed of basic primitives. From the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.

Regarding your actual question, you can use XPath as suggested by BoltClock. As you have seen, CasperJS provides the XPath utility which is usable outside of the page context.

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.click(x("//a[starts-with(.,'clickhere')]"));
```

[`starts-with(string, string)`](http://zvon.org/comp/r/ref-XPath_1.html#Functions~starts-with) is an XPath 1.0 function to check if some string starts with another string.

If you want to use this only to retrieve the element based on the starting text and then do something else with it, you can use the client utils of CasperJS for that inside the page context. It provides for example the function [`getElementByXPath`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#getelementbyxpath):

```
casper.evaluate(function(){
    var element = __utils__.getElementByXPath("//a[starts-with(.,'clickhere')]");
    // do something with element
});
```

The `__utils__` property is injected by CasperJS into the page context for every page.

The `.` in the XPath is the complete text that is inside this element whereas `text()` would only select text nodes that are directly inside the `a` element. Since the text that you use to select the `a` element is inside of the `b` element, you need to either use `.` like shown above or select the `b` element and then go to the parent:

```
"//a/b[starts-with(text(),'clickhere')]/.."
```